# Prove that if $ 11 | S_n, $ then $ 11| n $.

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

$S_n$ is defined as the alternate sum. For example, $S_{3522} = 2 - 2 + 5 - 3.$

Here n is obviously the number.

I know it has something to do with alternate sums and 1 mod 11 but cannot figure out how to proceed ...

Comment: What is $S_n $?

Comment: Check it again please

Answer (score 3):

In decimal notation $A=a_{n-1}a_{n-2}\cdots a_1a_0$ is the number
$\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a_j10^j$. As $10\equiv-1\pmod{11}$ then
$A\equiv\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}a_j(-1)^j\pmod{11}$.

Comment: What about the alternating sum?